# Unable to connect to Websocket address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to connect over an websocket address but my script is trowing an error on data recovery.

```
import requests
from websocket import create_connection

def conWs():
    ws = create_connection('wss://olymptrade.com/ds/v3')
    #ws.send('[{"t":1,"e":105,"d":[{"source":"platform"}]}]')
    #ws.send('[{"t":2,"e":90,"uuid":"JR20G7HQ62P0DURZO6F"}]')

    print(ws.connected)

    while True:
        result = ws.recv()
        print ("Received '%s'" % result)
```

I was expecting it to connect and start to receive websocket data, but the script breaks on with the error below:

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

Comment: Is something refreshing before the connection is completed? Or does `create_connection` take a long time to complete?

Comment: No, its is fast, `print(ws.connected)` it prints `True`, the first result prints nothing (`' '`), after that the script breaks.

Comment: Ok. I think I found a partial answer. It seems like there is a lot more leg work involved with keeping the connection open forever. Please have a look at the docs and let me know how it goes: https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to use a different approach.

> #### Short-lived one-off send-receive
>
> This (your code above) is if you want to communicate a short message and disconnect immediately when done.

Take a look at the example for **Long-lived connection** [in the docs](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) and please let me know if these modifications work for you. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Scott, I have tried but it looks like is stuck at the same place, the text is big so I've made an screenshot: https://imgur.com/I78sQ5e

You can see how it looks like on the Chrome Browser when navigating on the website platform: https://imgur.com/a/tyhcg07

Note that It gives me this `send: b"\x88\x82'\xaa\xc0\x15$B"` , maybe it is some kind of handshake?